# Redirects in .htaccess file for non-www domains except subdomains and dev domains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I will redirect all **non-www domains** in my Laravel .htaccess to a **www-domain**, *except* subdomains and development domains (*.app).

I have an application with multiple domainnames, now I use a long list in my htaccess, but that's a bad way...

```
# bad way :(
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1.com [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# etc... a very long list...
```

How can i redirect all non-www-domains to a www-version:

- **except** normal subdomains (like http://sub.example.com)
- **except** my development domains (like example.app)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.app$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[\w-]+\.[\w-]+\.(com|be|de|co\.uk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI{ [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: Sorry... This is not for MULTIPLE domains. I will a general rule for ALL my domains...

Comment: This is indeed a general rule with 2 exception 1. subdomain and 2. example.app. This rule will affect all other domains.

Comment: Yes but when I paste your code in my htaccess, he redirects all subdomains to a www domain. Like: http://sub.test.com to http://www.sub.test.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155071/discussion-between-angelique000-and-anubhava).